# org.gradle.api.GradleException: Please fix the version conflict either

Tags: android, api, google-maps, firebase-authentication

I'm building an android app with Firebase and Maps APIs but I'm getting the following error:

*Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 12.0.1.*

Here's what I have in the build.gradle module:app file. Any chance someone can help identify what conflict is happening here?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.simcoder.uber"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',  
{
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.0'
compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'

compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: have you updated firebase versions to the latest ones i.e 15 ?

Comment: This actually did sort the problem out, thanks :)

Comment: no problem. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this, needed to update the `Firebase versions` to the latest and I **removed** `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'`